# c# spilt string accourding to PCL Command

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string

```
str = E         TAX INVOICE             F
```

that I want to divide into 3 parts like

```
part 1= 'E'
part 2= '         TAX INVOICE             '
part 3= 'F'
```

where the split is done by *E* and *F*.

I tried

```
string[] strArr = Regex.Split(line, "E" + "|" + "F");
```

but only got

```
'         TAX INVOICE             '
```

in array and I also need 'E' and 'F' in it.

Comment: If you always have single characters, why not just get the characters at both ends and the substring in between?

Comment: @shree.pat18 no i have multiple split criteria

Comment: Then you should add that here. Based on your sample alone, Regex seems like overkill.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I agree, on this example substring and IndexOf gets it done

Answer (score 0):

**If you really need to use the E and F**

You can of course just create new array containing also *E* and *F* with your RegEx result.

As **RegEx** you can do include the delimiters by adding parentheses around the RegEx like

```
(E|F)
```

but this still splits the string wrongly, if there is E inside the source string.

To match only E and F with spaces around it on both sides you can use

```
( E | F )
```

which still leaves the space inside the array, though.

**If you can use the spaces as delimiter**

Try this as second parameter of Regex.Split instead

```
[ ]{2,}
```

It matches 2 or more spaces together and thus splits the string into three parts as you wish.

```
string[] strArr = Regex.Split(line, "[ ]{2,}");
```

Comment: what about split criteria?

Comment: "T.I.N.   E  .:- 09615111804C   F TIN:09881902522  F.L:          G"
SPILT=E,F,G